# Is it possible to do custom style (CSS only) for select tag to "Drop-up" instead of "Dropdown"?

Tags: html, css

I created selection box using select tag

```
<select class="c_selection">
  <option class="c_placeholder" value="" disabled selected>24h</option>
  <option value="1">10h</option>
  <option value="1">6h</option>
  <option value="1">3h</option>
  <option value="0">5mn</option>
</select>
```

but by default this will display a box with dropdown option. I want to know whether we can do custom style to make it "dropup" with only css style.

Comment: It is not possible to make this happen using the default `select`. You can see this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropup_hover .You can achieve this by creating a custom "drop-up"


"`SELECT` element behaviour is determined by the browser. It alone detects overflow outside of the viewport and will sometimes reposition the list. You can't control this directly."

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have checked this also, but because this used link as you mentioned, I want to use select tag so once I implement it with JS it would be easier to pass the value. Anyway, thank you.